# How can i run a command in the terminal and instead of logging in the terminal window, i redirect it to a file

Tags: linux, bash, github-actions

i would like to write the log output of running a command in the terminal to a file. I want the log output to be saved despite of whether the command ran into an error or not. This should work for any command in the  CLI `(Iam using ubuntu-latest for github actions)`
some sample code in app.js

```js
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
 console.log(i);
}
```

The following command works well

```
nohup node node-app/src/app.js &> logs.txt
```

But when an error occurs (i am adding `y` to cause the error)

```js
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
 console.log(i*y); //here is an error
}
```

The above terminal command fails and the `job` ends with an exit code 1.

Here is my workflow

```yaml
name: Send Job Logs to mail

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  send_email:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - id: logsData
      run: |
       nohup node node-app/src/app.js &> logs.txt
       cat logs.txt
       echo "logdata<<EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       echo "$(tail -n +2 logs.txt)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       echo "EOF" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       
    - name: Send log output to email
      uses: dawidd6/action-send-mail@v3
      with:
        server_address: smtp.gmail.com
        server_port: 25 
        username: ${{secrets.EMAIL_ADD}}
        password: ${{secrets.PSW_EMAIL}}
        from: john Delvin
        to: myOtherEmail@gmail.com
        subject: job-logs
        body: ${{env.logdata}}
```

Comment: where does y initialize?

Comment: y  is responsible for the error. I added it knowingly

Comment: So run your command(s) under the control of `script` ...

Comment: @JohnDelvin: Please include a minimal reproducible GHA workflow in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnDelvin: does the posted answer not work for your use case? What is the behavior now?

Comment: @Azeem , the answer provided by @Sibtain prevents the workflow job from  failing, in the step with `- id : logsData` , once error occurs, the step is ommited and then the next step is started which completes successfuly .

Comment: @JohnDelvin: Try with `nohup node node-app/src/app.js &> logs.txt || true` and without `continue-on-error: true`.

Comment: @Azeem it has worked. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDelvin: Awesome! You're welcome! Answer with details posted. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your use case requires you to run the rest of the commands in case there's a failure, you need to use something like this with [OR (`||`) operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

```
nohup node node-app/src/app.js &> logs.txt || true
```

This will return `true` if the command fails and the rest of the flow should run.

Using `continue-on-error: true` makes the step pass but it stops execution right away and the rest of the flow is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `continue-on-error: true` within your step / job, something like this:

```
- id: logsData
  continue-on-error: true
  run: nohup node app.js &> logs.txt
- name: output log file
  run: cat logs.txt
```

**Update with Demo execution:**

[image]

Comment: I need to save the log output into a file whether an error occurs or not.  Your answer a works but the log is not saved. Thanks

Comment: The log file is saved and available. You can use it in the next step, which was not mentioned in the original question. See my update

Comment: It worked .  This is much cleaner too